# Remove rows using another subset data frame

Tags: r

From a full dataframe:

```
df1 <- data.frame(pid = c(12,13,14,15,16,17,32,44,3,4,59,2,91), 
                 name = c("product1","product2","product3","product4",
                 "product5","product6","product7","product8","product9",
                 "product10","product11","product12","product43"))
```

Using an index/subset list like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(pid = c(12,13,14,4,2))
```

How could it be possible to remove the rows of df1 which have the pid values of df2?

Comment: `df1[!df1$pid %in% df2$pid,]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%in%`.

```
> df1[!df1$pid %in% df2$pid, ]
   pid      name
4   15  product4
5   16  product5
6   17  product6
7   32  product7
8   44  product8
9    3  product9
11  59 product11
13  91 product43
```